# How to get proper difference value between two days using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calculating the day difference between two day using JavaScript. For some cases I am getting right result but some cases I cannot get the right result. My code is below:

```
function caldate(){
       var difference=Math.abs((parseInt(document.getElementById('dayto').value)%7)-(parseInt(document.getElementById('dayfrom').value)%7))+1;
           alert(difference);
}
```

Here when `day to` is Sunday I am getting the wrong result. My [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/pOpDhTmRdJ8fbGj1vvvO?p=preview) is here. I need to calculate the difference between two day including both selected days.

Comment: Why are you changing the values with `.abs()` and `%7`, just compare the values

Comment: @adeneo : suppose i selected `from day=wedensday` and `to day=sunday` the difference should `5` .

Comment: it is 5 if you remove `%7`

Comment: The values are numeric strings, just subtract them, as in `value1 - value2`,  and if you want to avoid negative numbers wrap the whole thing in a `Math.abs` call

Comment: Question: If `dayfrom` is greater than `dayto`, are we to assume another that day, but in next week?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `%`?

```js
function caldate() {
  var day1 = document.getElementById('dayfrom').value;
  var day2 = document.getElementById('dayto').value;
  var difference = Math.abs((parseInt(document.getElementById('dayto').value)) - (parseInt(document.getElementById('dayfrom').value))) + 1;

  if (isNaN(difference)) {
    return true;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<p>Difference between day " +
    day1 + " and day " +
    day2 + " is: " +
    difference + " day" +
    (difference > 1 ? "s" : '') +
    "</p>" +
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML

}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Day From :</span>
    <select id="dayfrom">
      <option value="">Select day</option>
      <option value="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="3">Wedensday</option>
      <option value="4">Thrusday</option>
      <option value="5">Friday</option>
      <option value="6">Saturday</option>
      <option value="7">Sunday</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Day To :</span>
    <select id="dayto">
      <option value="">Select day</option>
      <option value="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="3">Wedensday</option>
      <option value="4">Thrusday</option>
      <option value="5">Friday</option>
      <option value="6">Saturday</option>
      <option value="7">Sunday</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="caldate();" value="Check">
<div id="output"></div>
```